# Android Sqlite select query between two date range

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing an issue in a select statement.
I need to query all rows between a particular start date and end date.
Here, i am getting only 1 row as the result. 
I need to select rows between 1st june and 3rd june including it.
I have tried with logdate and intime[timestamp] with the 'BETWEEN' . but still not solved.

[image]

```
select * from tablename where intime BETWEEN 1559327495307  AND  1559586580693  ORDER BY intime DESC;
```

Let me share my table data:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE testdb (_id integer primary key autoincrement, logdate text ,intime text,outtime text ,lastmodified text,breaktime text,timesheet text);
INSERT INTO `testdb` (_id,logdate,intime,outtime,lastmodified,breaktime,timesheet) VALUES (1,'07-Jun-2019','1559878500000','1559909160000','1559909291040',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `testdb` (_id,logdate,intime,outtime,lastmodified,breaktime,timesheet) VALUES (2,'06-Jun-2019','1559792880000','1559825400000','1559902319314',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `testdb` (_id,logdate,intime,outtime,lastmodified,breaktime,timesheet) VALUES (3,'01-Jun-2019','1559908893111','1559919690015','1559908893111',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO `testdb` (_id,logdate,intime,outtime,lastmodified,breaktime,timesheet) VALUES (4,'02-Jun-2019','1559434140000','1559479500000','1559909367627',NULL,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: SELECT  *
FROM    cituslog 
WHERE   intime >= '155943140000' AND
        To_date   <= '15554795000'

Comment: What does `intime` represent?  Is that a UNIX timestamp, or something else?  What is the _type_ of the `intime` column?  Is it text, numeric, etc.?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's UNIX timestamp

Comment: Your timestamps look slightly off to me, but that being said, other than that, your current logic should be working.

Comment: Are you sure the records are just like your screen says?

Comment: intime , its your column name .  SELECT * FROM cituslog WHERE intime >= '155943140000' AND outtime <= '15554795000' .

Comment: @MiniChip  0 rows returned in 0ms

Comment: have you tried changing the milliseconds ? SELECT * FROM cituslog WHERE intime <= '1559434140000' AND intime >= '1559908893111'

Comment: It should be working , even the between should work .

Comment: @Rasheed do you want to get results for `logdate` or intime/outtime?

Comment: @forpas i need to get results for any of it : based on logdate or intime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `logdate` column contains dates in a non comparable format.
SQLite is not that flexible in such cases, so you need to reformat the dates to `'yyyy-mm-dd'` and this is not easy as your current format is `'dd-MMM-yyyy'`:

```
select * from testdb 
where 
  substr(logdate, 8, 4) || '-' ||
  case substr(logdate, 4, 3)
    when 'Jan' then '01'
    when 'Feb' then '02'
    when 'Mar' then '03'
    when 'Apr' then '04'
    when 'May' then '05'
    when 'Jun' then '06'
    when 'Jul' then '07'
    when 'Aug' then '08'
    when 'Sep' then '09'
    when 'Oct' then '10'
    when 'Nov' then '11'
    when 'Dec' then '12'
  end || '-' ||
  substr(logdate, 1, 2) between '2019-06-01' and '2019-06-03'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u8ACLy2JkJxvue8wKUR7yK/0).
Results:

```
| _id | logdate     | intime        | outtime       | lastmodified  | breaktime | timesheet |
| --- | ----------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | --------- | --------- |
| 3   | 01-Jun-2019 | 1559908893111 | 1559919690015 | 1559908893111 |           |           |
| 4   | 02-Jun-2019 | 1559434140000 | 1559479500000 | 1559909367627 |           |           |
```